# Making change given the amount Scheme procedure

Tags: scheme, racket

The following code is to find out how many different ways can we make change given half-dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies?
Can someone explain how this procedure executes? How the cc function recurses?
I tried tracing this procedure but I am not sure how the cc function can recurse when it
subtracts the amount from the same denomination each time the function is called wouldn't
the amount eventually reach 0? Also, I don't understand why are there 2 different recursive calls to cc? Any help would be appreciated.

```
      (define (count-change amount)
      (cc amount 5))
      (define (cc amount kinds-of-coins)
      (cond ((= amount 0) 1)
      ((or (< amount 0) (= kinds-of-coins 0)) 0)
      (else (+ (cc amount
      (- kinds-of-coins 1))
      (cc (- amount
      (first-denomination kinds-of-coins))
        kinds-of-coins)))))
     (define (first-denomination kinds-of-coins)
     (cond ((= kinds-of-coins 1) 1)
     ((= kinds-of-coins 2) 5)
     ((= kinds-of-coins 3) 10)
     ((= kinds-of-coins 4) 25)
     ((= kinds-of-coins 5) 50)))
     (count-change 10)
```

Comment: Try the stepper in DrRacket. (Choose the beginner language. Enter your example. Then click the foot).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is that the amount will eventually be zero; this is when the recursion ends.
(You might want to review your introduction to recursion.)

It executes like this:

- If there is no change amount, there is exactly one way to give change,
- If you don't have any coins, there is no way to give change,
- Otherwise, you have two choices:

  - Don't use the largest available coin, but give change on the whole amount using the smaller coins (the first recursion), or
  - Use one of the largest coins, and give change on the remaining sum using all coins (the second recursion),
  - And the result is the sum of these two options.